# How to show the item selected in Datagrid distinctive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am using Datagrid control to populate list of items/contents. I want to show what row has been selected, distinctive.

What property of the datagrid control should i use ?

How do i do this ?

Thanks
Ron.

Comment: I think its 'SelectedItemStyle'. Example: <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="Yellow"></SelectedItemStyle>.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I saw that while googling, and tried it, but nothing is happening after i selected a row...

Comment: this is the code i have:

Comment: <asp:DataGrid id="HistoryListGrid" 
            runat="server" 
            Width="100%" 
            CellPadding="15"
            CellSpacing="15"
            AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#dddddd"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            EnableViewState="False" SelectedItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"
            GridLines="Horizontal">
            <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="Red" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<SelectedItemStyle BackColor="Pink" ForeColor="Green" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SelectedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx) Property is perhaps what you need

```
void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;

    // Display the company name from the selected row.
    // In this example, the third column (index 2) contains
    // the company name.
    MessageLabel.Text = "You selected " + row.Cells[2].Text + ".";

  }
```

Comment: Hi kd7, I am not able to retain the selecteditemstyle properties during the postback. The selected row doesnt highligt. the code i have is :

Comment: <asp:DataGrid id="HistoryListGrid" 
            runat="server" 
            Width="100%" 
            CellPadding="15"
            CellSpacing="15"
            AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#dddddd"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            EnableViewState="False" SelectedItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"
            GridLines="Horizontal">
            <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="Red" />

Answer (score 0):

Ron, DataGrid hasnt default behaviour for row selecting. You should do it yourself:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="DataGridTest" SelectedIndex="1" OnItemCreated="DataGridTest_ItemCreated" DataSourceID="DataSourceTmp">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="HighlightText" Font-Bold="true" />
    <ItemStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#bbbbff" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
  private const string DataGridSelectedRowCssClass = "selectedRow";

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
      GetType(),
      "dataGrid_selectRow",
      string.Format(
        @"(function (dataGrid, $, undefined) {{

          dataGrid.selectRow = function (row) {{

            $(row).siblings('.{0}').css('background-color', '#{1}').end().css('background-color', '#{2}').addClass('{0}');
            }}

          }})(window.dataGrid = window.dataGrid || {{}}, jQuery);",
        DataGridSelectedRowCssClass,
        DataGridTest.ItemStyle.BackColor.ToArgb().ToString("X8").Substring(2), 
        DataGridTest.SelectedItemStyle.BackColor.ToArgb().ToString("X8").Substring(2)),
      true);
  }

  protected void DataGridTest_ItemCreated(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem)
    {
      e.Item.Attributes["onclick"] = "dataGrid.selectRow(this);";

      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem)
      {
        e.Item.CssClass = string.Format("{0} {1}", e.Item.CssClass, DataGridSelectedRowCssClass);
      }
    }
  }
}
```